# How to upload a react-native app to ios app market without expo?

Tags: ios, swift, react-native

I saw documentation on https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device but there is no explanation to upload market. 
I saw some blog posts, They are telling we want manually bundle `js` for ios.

Please give me the correct information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fastlane is the easiest way to go if you haven't done it before or you are unfamiliar with the process.

Follow the simple [installation steps](https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/ios/setup/).

After that, you'll need to create two lanes in your Fastfile similar to these (probably you'll need to do some modifications):

```
platform :ios do

lane :release do
        cert // handle the ios certificates
        sigh // sign the code
        sigh(app_identifier: "your.app.identifier") // get it from XCode > General tab > Bundle identifier
        gym(export_method: 'app-store') // build the app
end

lane :upload_to_appstore do
        appstore(
            username: 'your email',
            ipa: 'your app.ipa',
            automatic_release: false,
            skip_metadata: true,
            skip_screenshots: true,
            submit_for_review: false
        )
end

end
```

Note: You need to have certificates. If you don't, you can easily create them with Fastlane. And of course, you need to have an apple developer account.

Then just execute `fastlane ios release` and `fastlane ios upload_to_appstore`.